# Selenium window retrieve same values if Window is not in focus

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

Anyone's getting this issue when you're controlling a window with Selenium.

I am using Selenium to scrape some public value. I notice quite often that if the window is not on top (in focus ?), **the value is still retrieved but obsolete and stays the same**.
When I deliberately **click on the Selenium window** to bring it to focus again, the value is then updated.

I tried

```
driver.execute_script("window.focus();")
```

but the problem is not solved.

Comment: Which *"public values"* do you want to scrape? What *"click on the Selenium window"* should mean?

Comment: Meaning: From Jupyter notebook I run Selenium to open a Chrome window A. It should be getting an updated number on that window. You let the notebook do its work and switch to other things (another Chrome window B and C, or window explorer, or any application). Selenium should be getting values e.g. 5,2,7,9,3,5,2... but it only does so for certain time. After about 15-30 min the value flatlines 5,2,7,9,9,9,9,9,9,9.. unless you deliberately click on the Chrome window A to bring it up. At that point Selenium "wakes up" and pick up new values : 5,2,7,9,9,9,9,9,...9,9,5,3,7,4,5.As if it needs focus